# How to enable scroll for ListView while disabling the click on it in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView`. When I click on a row it flickers on Android app. I just want to disable this flickering. I have tried setting the `IsEnabled` property to `false`. But in this case, I cannot scroll by moving my finger up and down.
So it there any way to stop this flickering without affecting other events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the IsEnabled property to the ViewCell, not on the Listview:

```
<ViewCell IsEnabled="false">
    //Your Item Layout Coding
</ViewCell>
```

Another solution is unselecting instantly in the ItemTappedEvent:

```
YourList.ItemSelected+=DeselectItem;

 public void DeselectItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
  }
```